# Why doesn't CBC find the Pyomo warmstart file?

Tags: pyomo

I'm trying to use the warmstart/mipstart option for the CBC solver 2.10.3 with Pyomo 5.7.3.
It seems to me that CBC expects a relative path to the warmstart solution file, whereas Pyomo provides an absolute path.
Is that right? And if so, are there any working alternative ways to provide CBC with a warmstart solution?
Thank you very much, Stefan

### Details:

First, I store a warmstart solution from a heuristic:

```
for assignment in heuristic_solution.assignments:
   model.xvars[assignment] = assignment.count
```

Then I ask Pyomo to call the CBC solver:

```
solver_factory.solve(model, warmstart=True)
```

Pyomo successfully creates a warmstart file (in line 267 of pyomo/solvers/plugins/solvers/CBCplugin.py):

```
self._warm_start_file_name = TempfileManager.create_tempfile(suffix = '.cbc.soln')
```

Pyomo then hands this file name over to CBC by creating a command line:

```
C:\<...>\cbc.exe -import C:\<...>\problem.lp -mipstart C:\<...>\warmstart.cbc.soln -solve
```

However, the _warm_start_file_name is an absolute path, whereas CBC accepts only relative paths. Thus, the warmstart solution is not being read by CBC.